# How do I fetch the cookies being passed in the Request header of my admin login page for my Jmeter?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies, jmeter, request

I have recorded a script through blazemeter. The script is not able to capture the cookies being passed in the request header of my admin login page. How do I capture the same/handle it -  if I don't get the cookies in the response?

cookie - _ga=GA1.3.446677307.1649256387; __stripe_mid=f9978437-7dca-4955-ae17-222cc2117a67b70de2; _fbp=fb.2.1649256491328.2062923856; wp-settings-8=libraryContent=browse&editor=tinymce; wp-settings-time-8=1649413701; PHPSESSID=7ofrae0qeoqv347olpdn6rqqpl; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; tk_ai=woo:halNW3T7X/6Ia5YoObVl4yEC; _gid=GA1.3.1612413055.1651476472; wordpress_sec_7167849bb4504fbe38860cc54341b5e7=kong-central|1651654276|OsXQ2WhnyoWLpjvghw48naC2fpDxT9cLLVVNO0lfgsx|c9058cac622de729cf0feb5a1f08894a096978637cf8d8e1fdb6e94160ba7cac; wordpress_logged_in_7167849bb4504fbe38860cc54341b5e7=kong-central|1651654276|OsXQ2WhnyoWLpjvghw48naC2fpDxT9cLLVVNO0lfgsx|2becdbe8d3b53ed397d000a2fff652fd30109420ce0476c1784dcde043e94444; __stripe_sid=7874b226-9324-4055-9f7c-6c42d6aa7f3599ff82; wp_woocommerce_session_7167849bb4504fbe38860cc54341b5e7=9fda078a293d1a2c0ba86f5655d3cf78||1651654373||1651650773||9adaf51156413fd8ff50f4b6d99364f7

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to record cookies because they change each time you open the page with a new user.

It's sufficient to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan and it will automatically extract incoming cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header and add them to the [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header of the next request if the cookie is OK (it's not expired, domain and path match the ones in the cookie, etc.)

Also be informed that in JMeter's [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener outgoing cookies are listed under Request -> Request Data tabs:

[image]

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Add HTTP Cookie manager, it would do your work
if you want to change the value for every iteration then select the check box stating clear cookies for every iteration